# Count distinct operation for a window with partition by, order by and range between in spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I have a dataframe which looks like this -

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
|DeviceId | TimeString       | UnixTimestamp | Group |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|8313726  | 2023-10-17 01:00 | 1697529600    | g1    |
|0065322  | 2023-10-17 01:00 | 1697529600    | g2    |
|2902499  | 2023-10-17 00:00 | 1697526000    | g2    |
|1506928  | 2023-10-17 00:00 | 1697526000    | g1    |
|7466245  | 2023-10-17 14:00 | 1697576400    | g3    |
+------------------+----------------+----------------+
```

The TimeString and UnixTimestamp columns are just hourly times in different formats.

I need the distinct count of devices in the past 12 hours window for each group.

This is what I tried -

```
val windowSpecLast12 = Window.partitionBy("Group").
orderBy(col("UnixTimestamp").cast(LongType)). // Order by the numeric timestamp
rangeBetween(-12 * 3600, -1) // 12 hours in seconds

// Define a UDF to calculate the distinct count of devices in an array of DeviceId
val distinctCountUDF = udf((ids: Seq[String]) => ids.distinct.size)

df = df.withColumn("DistinctCountLast12", distinctCountUDF(collect_list("DeviceId").over(windowSpecLast12)))
```

While this works, it is extremely slow as the data size is large and the UDF doesnt perform well.

I also tried to use dense_rank as a proxy to get distinct device count, like this -

```
df = df.withColumn("RankLast12", dense_rank().over(windowSpecLast12))
```

This gives an error -

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Window Frame specifiedwindowframe(RangeFrame, -43200, -1) must match the required frame specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), currentrow$());
```

Any suggestions ?
Can spark SQL do this better ? If yes, how ?

Edit 1 -

I should have been more specific about what I am looking for - I need the distinct count of devices in the past 12 hours window for each group and TimeString (or UnixTimestamp) combination. Something like this -

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
| Group | TimeString       | UniqueDevicesPast12Hours|
+----------------------------------------------------+
| g1    | 2023-10-17 00:00 |  1xxx                   |
| g2    | 2023-10-17 01:00 |  2xxx                   |
| g2    | 2023-10-17 00:00 |  3xxx                   |
| g1    | 2023-10-17 01:00 |  2xxx                   |
| g3    | 2023-10-17 14:00 |  1xxx                   |
+------------------+----------------+----------------+
```

interpretation - row 1 is number of distinct devices seen for group g1 in the 12 hour window preceding the TimeString 2023-10-17 00:00 (not included), or in more simpler terms, number of unique device Ids seen for group g1 in the interval 2023-10-16 12:00 to 2023-10-16 23:00 (both included).

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{window,countDistinct}
import spark.implicits._ 
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

// Created dataframe based on your table
val df = sc.parallelize(Array((8313726, "2023-10-17 01:00", 1697529600, "g1"),(1065322, "2023-10-17 01:00", 1697529600, "g2" ),(2902499, "2023-10-17 00:00", 1697526000, "g2" ),(1506928, "2023-10-17 00:00", 1697526000, "g1" ),(7466245, "2023-10-17 14:00", 1697576400, "g3"))).toDF("DeviceId" , "TimeString" , "UnixTimestamp" , "Group").withColumn("TimeString",col("TimeString").cast("timestamp"))

// below code you can use to get distinct count for last 12 hours
val df2 = df.groupBy($"Group",window($"TimeString","12 hours")).agg(countDistinct($"DeviceId").as("DistinctCountLast12"))
```

Below is the sample result
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response @karthik. I made an edit to make it more clear as to what I am looking to do.